# Index out bounds exception when storing time in milliseconds [Android]

Tags: android, kotlin, long-integer, timepicker, android-timepicker

I am storing time in Milliseconds using a Material Time Picker Dialog. The problem is if I choose a time instance which is like a single valued hour (between 1-9) or single valued minute(1-9) then I am able to get the value in milliseconds. But if I set the bigger values of time I get an exception `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=17; index=20`

What am I doing wrong here? Or what is the better approach to do this.

**Log for reference :**

[image]

**My Code (Not the complete code but what is required for this question) :**

```
 //Time Picker
    var picker: MaterialTimePicker = MaterialTimePicker()

    //Long values to be stored in database
    val timeStart: Long = 0


 //Setting Start Time
        binding.timeStart.setOnClickListener {
            openTimePicker()
            picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
                val h = picker.hour
                val m = picker.minute
                binding.timeStart.text = "$h:$m"
                Timber.d("Start Time - h: $h m: $m")
                try {
                    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                    calendar.get(h)
                    calendar.get(m)
                    val timeInMilliSeconds = calendar.timeInMillis
                    Timber.d("$timeInMilliSeconds")
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Timber.d("$e")
                }
            }
        }

 private fun openTimePicker() {
        val isSystem24Hour = is24HourFormat(requireContext())
        val clockFormat = if (isSystem24Hour) TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H else TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H

        picker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setTimeFormat(clockFormat)
            .setHour(12)
            .setMinute(10)
            .setTitleText("Set Start Time")
            .build()
        picker.show(childFragmentManager, "TAG")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's happening here:

```
val h = picker.hour
val m = picker.minute
binding.timeStart.text = "$h:$m"
Timber.d("Start Time - h: $h m: $m")
try {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.get(h)
    calendar.get(m)
    val timeInMilliSeconds = calendar.timeInMillis
    Timber.d("$timeInMilliSeconds")
}
```

Specifically when you call [`calendar.get()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#get(int))

> `public int get (int field)`
>
> Returns the value of the given **calendar field**
> Throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`   if the specified field is out of range `(field < 0 || field >= FIELD_COUNT)`

> `public static final int FIELD_COUNT`
>
> The number of distinct fields recognized by `get` and `set`. Field numbers range from `0..FIELD_COUNT-1`
>
> Constant Value: **17**

That's why your exception is complaining that the array has **17** items and you're trying to access index **20**, because you're passing values representing *hours* and *minutes* instead of *field constants*.

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly, but look at the `set` or `add` methods in the `Calendar` class, if you want to specify an exact time or you want to add *x* hours and *y* minutes to the current time. You'll need to use the field constants to specify which value you're changing, e.g. [`HOUR_OF_DAY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#HOUR_OF_DAY)

---

**edit** Ok, so I think there's a bit of confusion about what `Calendar` *does*, and you've explained what you're trying to do, so I'll show you a few options you have.

I'm not sure which of these you want to do though - when the user enters a time on the clock, do you:

- treat them as *a number of hours and minutes*, total them up and convert to milliseconds
- treat them as a *time*, and work out how many milliseconds in the future that is *relative to the current time*

Here's how you can handle both of those things:

**Total hours + mins, in millis**

```
// basic calculation - 1000s in 1ms, 60s in 1m, 60m in 1h
val minsAsMillis = m * 60 * 1000
val hoursAsMillis = h * 60 * 60 * 1000
val totalMillis = minsAsMillis + hoursAsMillis

// or use a utility class like Duration, TimeUnit etc
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
val millis = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours)
    + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(mins)

// the java.time classes require desugaring on APIs earlier than 26 I think - see below
import java.time.Duration
val millis = Duration.ofMinutes(m.toLong())
    .plusHours(hours.toLong())
    .toMillis()
```

**Future time, calculate millis from now til then**

This one's trickier, because it involves getting *now* as a clock time, which relates to things like the user's current locale, the time of year (for things like daylight savings changes) and so on. This *is* what `Calendar` is for, working with times and dates.

There are a lot of utility classes around time, and I'm not super-familiar with it all, so this might not be *the best* way to do this - but here's something that should work:

```
// implies the system default locale and time-zone - you can provide those if necessary
val now = Calendar.getInstance()
val future = Calendar.getInstance()
// set the future time
future.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h)
future.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m)
// need to clear the millis field (since it's based off the current time)
future.set(Calendar.MILLIS, 0)

// since the user's setting a clock time, that could be -earlier- than the
// current time (e.g. it's 5pm and they've chosen 10:50am). Assuming that
// should be treated as -tomorrow-, we might need to add a day

// using !after so it also matches -right now-, just in case
if (!future.after(now)) future.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24)
```

Now you have your two `Calendars` (which represent a specific date and time remember) you can work out the difference between them. You were calling `getTimeInMillis()` before - because a `Calendar` really just represents a point in time, that method gives you the number of milliseconds since the *epoch*, i.e. the start of the year 1970. Probably a bigger number than you were expecting!

But that's a useful number to have (e.g. the current time is `System.currentTimeInMillis()`) because when you have two of them, you can compare the distance between them. So we can do this:

```
val durationInMillis = future.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis()
```

There are some other classes like `LocalDateTime`, `Instant`, `Duration` etc that might be useful (and even preferable, this seems like a fairly simple use-case though) but you might have to enable desugaring to get them on earlier APIs since they're Java 8+ features. [Info here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) if you want to look into that

Comment: Basically I want to take the time from TimePicker (which is entered by the user) and I am doing that here `val h = picker.hour` and `val m = picker.minute` and then I want to convert this entered time to milliseconds so that I can store the value in Room Database.
I am getting the error with `get()` method, then how would I resolve it? How would I convert the time entered to milliseconds. Is there any other way to do it, instead of using Calendar?

Comment: @oyeraghib the `get` method takes a *field constant* which is an int code that represents the particular value you want to get - the constants are listed on the documentation page (e.g. `MINUTE` happens to be `4`). Think about it - if the user enters *20 minutes*, and you call `get(20)`, how would the `Calendar` know what that means? 20 what? And besides, that's not really how a `Calendar` works or what it's for. I'll add to my answer in a bit and explain it!

Comment: I was able to solve it with the `TimeUnit.HOURS.ToMilli(myHours)` method, thanks a lot for great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to get the time in milliseconds using `TimeUnit` instead of Calendar. I used `TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(myHours)` and `TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(myMinutes)` to get my hours and minutes in milliseconds and then add them to get the time in milliseconds.

Code :

```
binding.timeStart.setOnClickListener {
            openTimePicker()
            picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
                val h = picker.hour
                val m = picker.minute
                binding.timeStart.text = "$h:$m"
                Timber.d("Start Time - $h: $m")
                try {
                    val hour = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(h.toLong())
                    val minute = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(m.toLong())
                    val totalTime = hour + minute

                    Timber.d("Hour - $hour, Minute - $minute, Total = $totalTime")
                    timeStart = totalTime

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Timber.d("$e")
                }
            }
        }

    private fun openTimePicker() {
        picker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
            .setHour(12)
            .setMinute(10)
            .setTitleText("Set Start Time")
            .build()
        picker.show(childFragmentManager, "TAG")
    }
```